# Service layer in java swing application

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, swing, service-layer

i'm thinking if i really need a service layer.

I'm using spring + hibernate for a desktop swing application and at this moment i have gui/swing layer->service layer->dao layer. I use spring only for @Transactional support and for IOC-injection

Best practice say that i have to write a service to use my daos, and put all transactions management in the service.

But i'm realizing that very very often, service layer only replicate dao methods, so for example:

```
// a DAO example
@Repository
public class CustomerHibernateDAO extends BaseHibernateDAO implements CustomerDAO {

 public List<Customer> findAllCustomerILikeName(String name){
  return getSession()
   .createCriteria(Customer.class)
   .add(Restriction.ilike("name", name))
   .list();
 }
}

// Customer service to use this dao...
@Service
@Transactional
public class CustomerService {

 @Autowired
 CustomerDAO customerDAO;

 // Why i can't call DAO instead the service?
 public List<Customer> getAllCustomersByName(String name){
      return customerDAO.findAllCustomerILikeName(name);
 }

}
```

This is a mine tipical usage of service layer... Hibernate is db-agnostic, spring are tecnology-agnostic: so, i really need it?

What about a unique Service class to manage all DAO?? I think this may be a good compromise, or, is a bad practice?

I know put @Transactional on DAO is a bad way, but at this moment i have to write services only for put @Transactional on it...

**EDIT**

More infos about my app.

My application is a management software and manage user registration, products, order and other things like those.
In practice it contains a lot of read entity->edit->save entity or create->edit->save operations, and, thanks to hibernate, these operations are managed by ONE dao most of the time, becouse hibernate with @manyto... collection and cascade.save_update permits to save two or more entities in the same persist operation.

So, for example, in my items JFrame where i can insert, edit or create an Item(a product to sell) there are:

```
public ItemFrame(){
 // the constructor
 itemService=springAppContext.getBeans(ItemService.class);
}

public boolean validateForm(){
 // test if the gui is correctly filled by user
}

public boolean save(){
 // create an Item entity taking value from swing gui(JTextField etc)
 Item item=new Item();
 item.setName(nameTextField.getText());
 item.setEtc...
 // ItemService ' save method is a wrap around itemDao.save(item)...
 itemService.save(item);
}

private void saveItemActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
 // When i press SAVE button
 if(validateForm()){
  save();
 }
}
```

This is what i have in the most of cases, so i think i fell in anemic-domain-antipattern...

Thanks.

Comment: According to me you are doing it correctly.Services should be there per entity.It will maintain standard pattern + if there comes change in DB you will be just re building DAO layer ,+1 btw

Comment: If there comes change in DB and i did not use services, what the problem? I will just rebuild my DAO and all is fine...or not?

Comment: I'm getting a little off topic here, but what's the reason for getting the bean from the container yourself in ItemFrame constructor? I can't see any benefits of this approach over getting the bean injected by the container.

Comment: ItemFrame is instanced by new ItemFrame(), it is not a spring components, so @Autowired doesn't work here. Im new with spring but this is what i know...i hope it is correct.

Comment: Better way to do this: use @Configurable annotation...this way you can autowire to anything (even to entities created via hibernate (hibernate uses probably clazz.getinstance))...The only thing where autowired does not work for me are sevlets for some reason :-).... The configurable has only one drawback, you must use code instrumentation and some lines of config, but its pretty easy (about 3 lines of xml in appContext.xml, and if you are using tomcat one parameter (javaagent) in in its catalina-opts (spring-agent.jar path)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your service layer duplicates dao, you are not using service layer at all. I made the same mistake in few of my applications, I was wondering "why the service layer looks so ugly, and is duplicationg DAO"...

The service layer should be interface for your appliacation, this doest mean, that some methods are not the same in dao and in service, but the main part is significantly different. I cannot say this without viewing the rest of your code, but by your question (which is almost the same as were my questions few months ago), it seems to me, that you are using [anemic domain model antipattern](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html). In anemic domain model, your model contains only fields and getters, no real methods (behaviour), which violates fundamental object oriented principles (object == data + behaviour)...your behaviour is probably in something that looks like transaction script in service layer, but should be in your model (domain layer).

The way out of this is to use rich domain model (beans injected to model via @Configurable). You may say, that this violates the layers pattern and you will be probably correct. But I am convinced, that we should think about our application (domain+dao+service) as a single component (see Alistair Cockburn [Hexagonal architecture/Ports and adapters](http://alistair.cockburn.us/Hexagonal+architecture)).

Your swing app/web client will then be a client to your core component, you can then switch them without any limitations (beacause everything that modiefies data is in core).

But there is a limitation/drawback with this approach. If you will use some sort of security (Spring security) or active records via hibernate, than you should comunicate with all clients via DTO (not the entities itself), because when you contact entity, it may call service, which will active itself via transactional and can modify the database (bypass your security).

I hope, that I have guessed your architecture, if not, I am sorry for inventing the wheel here, but this post may help someone who doesnt know this (as was I few moths ago).

**EDIT**

to your edit: Even in simple CRUD application, some kind of actions should be in service layer - for example validation (not the validation "this is a number", but some business specific validation). This shouldn be in your view, because if you change it, you will have copy & paste it again. When you look at your code, you should ask a qeusting "if I decide to write thin client (view in web browser)", is there any code, that i will have to copy? If is the answer YES, than you should create an service method for this possibly remote call.

The other thing that you should/can do on service layer is autorization (is the user in this role permited to delete this entry). Than you will have to have an service layer for almost all of your entities, because simple user should be able to edit (delete) his entries, but probably should not delete other users. But user in role admin can do this.

Example code (part of article Service interface in my app (Spring security)):

```
@Secured("ROLE_EDITOR")
public void save(ArticleDTO selectedArticle, ArticleDetailsDTO selectedArticleDetails);
```

In comment service everybody can save their comments to articles....

And one last note: you should probably consider, if you *need* service layer at all. When its written in a nice way, your app will gain many qualities in its flexibility, reusability and maintainability. But it pretty hard and time consuming to write it. If you dont want to do this all this stuff (security, rich domain model, calling from more interfaces (changing view implementation)), you can live without it :-)

Comment: thank you very useful, i add more info to my first post, please leave a comment about it! Thank you!

Comment: My entities contain only getter and setter, but my daos contains more method than CRUD so they are real repository(in according to DDD, driven domanin design). When i write entity i try always to think in OO way. So i have a mix of anemic and domain model.

Comment: Great link, I wasn't aware that Fowler had an article on this.

Answer (score 1):

At some point, your application will want some business logic.  Also, you might want to validate the input to make sure that there isn't something evil or nonperforming being requested.  This logic belongs in your service layer.

Moreover, it may be possible to make your DAO quite generic, so that you only have one or two methods that don't change much.  This reduces the risk of doing something terribly wrong to your DAO classes every time you want to add/change the functionality of the app.

The DAO is for access data.  The Service is for business logic.  Keep them separate and you will be happier in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, you will need to coordinate behavior among multiple DAO's.  You may also introduce some complexity to your business rules (ex: don't update [this], if [that] is in a particular state).  This is where the service layer comes in handy.

That said, there is "technically" nothing wrong with eliminating the service layer altogether.  It will just be a little more painful when you eventually decide that you need one.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of enforcing

```
ui -> service -> DAO
```

for every operation, consider allowing both

```
ui -> DAO
ui -> service -> DAO
```

the latter being used for more complex operations